# CakePHP: authentication frontend and backend, are they possible together?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, frontend, backend

I'm developing a CakePHP 1.3 application which needs to login users backend and frontend.

On the backend, admins and others must login to edit pages and data.

On the frontend, users can login to see "private" pages.

I'm using CakePHP ACL/Auth to login backend users (but i dont'have so clear how it works).

What do you suggest? I was thinking to set frontend users as a particular "acl" group to see that pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User admin routing.( http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration )

This will allow you to create separate functionality for ADMINS and USERS. You can even create additional user types and create routes for them too.

ACL is a bit difficult to understand and does not make sense for all situations. This blog may be of some use to help you get started:
http://www.studiocanaria.com/articles/cakephp_auth_component_users_groups_permissions_revisited

Comment: The links are both broken.